# jQuery: change background color after animation completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with my jQuery right now. What I want is that the background color is changed after the animation completes. I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work. I don't understand there are no console errors.

http://jsfiddle.net/4pmzf/

jQuery:

```
$("#slider").toggle(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "height":"100px"
    }, 1000).addClass('red');
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "height":"20px"
    }, 1000).removeClass('red');
});
```

CSS

```
#slider {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [specificity issue](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity). The initial background declaration has a higher specificity because it was declared with an `id`. You could solve this by overwriting it with a more specific selector:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4y92Z/)

```
#slider.red {
    background:red;
}
```

The initial selector, `#slider`, has a specificity of 100.

The new selector, `#slider.red`, has a slightly higher specificity of 110.

Aside from this, the background really isn't being changed *after* the animation completes. I'd suggest adding a [callback/complete function](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) to the animation(s)..

[**CALLBACK EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xue2k/)

```
$("#slider").toggle(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "height":"100px"
    }, 1000, function(){
        $(this).css('background','red');
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        "height":"20px"
    }, 1000, function(){
        $(this).css('background','');
    });
});
```

Also.. rather than changing classes, it's probably better to just modify the CSS.

Comment: Thanks joshc, I now understand what i was doing wrong. I like the callback example very much!